# Calling server and client method in SignalR

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, signalr-hub

Below code with ASP.Net SignalR Hub technology. These codes are not working as expected. When I am clicking on Hello Butting it is working fine but when I am clicking on UserList nothing is happening. I have placed an alert and found server method is invoking but after that nothing happening.

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

    chat.client.OnlineFriends = function (userLists) {
        alert(userLists);
    };

    chat.client.Hello = function (message) {
        alert(message);
    };

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        $('#btnGetUser').click(function () {
            chat.server.Friends();
        });

        $('#btnHello').click(function () {                    
            chat.server.test("message to server from client");                    
            //
        });
    });
});
```

and C# code

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Test(string str)
    {
        Clients.Caller.Hello(str + " | Message received at server reply from server.");
    }
    public void Friends()
    {
        Clients.Caller.OnlineFriends("myid");
    }
}
```

and HTML

```
<div>

    <input type="button" id="btnHello" value="Hello" />
    <input type="button" id="btnGetUser" value="UserList" />
</div>
```

Please help to find out what is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try to change the line

```
chat.server.Friends();
```

to:

```
chat.server.friends();
```

I guess the generated javascript has the java convention on naming. That is the only difference I can see from those two methods.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @scheien you need to call the method using a lower case first letter. Optionally, you can specify the hub method name as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server).

```
[HubMethodName("MyNewMethodName")]
public void Friends()
```

and then call server functions using that new name

```
chat.server.MyNewMethodName();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chat.client.onlineFriends = function (userLists) {
        alert(userLists);
    };
```

but......  `userLists` does not exist on the hub:

```
Clients.CalleronlineFriends("myid");
```

This was one thing, and another thing that cought my eye was that the javascript part doesn't start with a capital letter

So you must also change `Friends` , `Hello` , `OnlineFriends` into `friends`, `hello` `onlineFriends`

Comment: only function name change from 'Friends' to 'friends' and all other method and variable name in lower case solve the problem. Variable name like userlists or message has not impacted anything. Thanks all for you reply. Finally It has solved my problem.

Comment: @SumanBiswas maybe the string was accepted by the function :) glad that you solved your problem :)

Comment: Thank you, both were my answer but stackoverflow does not allow to mark 2 answer hence i choose most correct one.